# Getting error on ionic cordova build android

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic3

Just started to learn ionic 3. Getting below error on `ionic cordova build android`

```
(node:6364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]
(node:6364) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Below is my ionic info.

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\HIT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

Node : v8.5.0
npm  : 5.3.0
OS   : Windows 10
Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : D:\AndroidSdk\platform-tools
Misc:

backend : pro
```

I wrote below promise code

```
 postData(credentials, type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = new Headers();

      this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json());
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

I call the `postData` function below

```
signup(){
    //Api connection
this.authService.postData(this.userData , "register.php").then((result) => {
    this.reposeData = result;
    console.log(this.reposeData);
    localStorage.setItem('userData' , JSON.stringify(this.reposeData))
    this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
}, (err) => {
    //connection failed
});
```

}

Is this my code issue?

Comment: The `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` comes from Cordova, not from your code. Try building with `--verbose` param and se if it gives some more information about the build error.

Comment: How to use -verbose @jcesarmobile

Comment: ionic cordova build android —verbose

Comment: --verbose not added to this project error @jcesarmobile

Comment: I don't understand your last comment

Comment: When i hit the ionic cordova build android —verbose. It's giving me error --verbose not added to this project

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it from the ipad and added strange characters instead of `--`, try with  `ionic cordova build android --verbose`

Comment: I tried this command only'

Comment: Please post the code where you call the function `postData`

Comment: @Duannx Hi updated my code.

Comment: Your error come frome `Unhandled promise rejections`. But your code above is fine. The rejection is handled. Is there any promise in your project?  Please check it

Answer (score 4):

According to the error message, you have not handled a rejection on one of your Promise objects. Each and every promise is expected to  have a .catch(...).

```
var flag = false;
var Test = function () {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
if (flag === true)
    resolve();
else
    reject();
});
}
var testFunc = Test();
testFunc.then(function () {
 alert("Promise Resolved");
});
testFunc.catch(function () {
 alert("Promise Rejected");
});
```

Read more about Promise Objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)